# C++ Overloaded Copysign Operator either conflicting or ambiguous

Tags: c++, open-source

I'm trying to solve a problem relating to what appears to be a now out of date Open Source game. As I want to play it, I'm trying to get it built and potentially be able to add some stuff to it.

Unfortunately, I am coming up against some problems and my C++ skills are admittedly lacking.

```
In file included from /home/talrose/projects/Vegastrike/engine/src/cmd/../gfx/camera.h:24:0,
             from /home/talrose/projects/Vegastrike/engine/src/cmd/beam_generic.cpp:8:
/home/talrose/projects/Vegastrike/engine/src/physics.h:30:34: error: ‘float copysign(float, float)’ conflicts with a previous declaration
float copysign( float x, float y );
                              ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/math.h:36:0,
             from /projects/Vegastrike/engine/src/vs_math.h:27,
             from /projects/Vegastrike/engine/src/vegastrike.h:36,
             from /projects/Vegastrike/engine/src/cmd/beam_generic.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/6/cmath:1288:3: note: previous declaration ‘constexpr float std::copysign(float, float)’
copysign(float __x, float __y)
   ^~~~~~~~
CMakeFiles/engine_com.dir/build.make:614: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/engine_com.dir/src/cmd/beam_generic.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/engine_com.dir/src/cmd/beam_generic.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:262: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/engine_com.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/engine_com.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

The physics.h file can be found [here](https://github.com/Taose/Vegastrike-taose/blob/master/engine/src/physics.h)

I have a feeling that previously, just having an infile declaration was enough to provide "preference" for the compiler, but now that isn't the case.  I would appreciate it if someone could explain the issue behind this so that I might better solve it in the future.

I've tried commenting it out and that leads to an ambiguity error in a much more in depth piece of code (over 4000 lines).

**Edits**

1. Applying **constexpr** in front of the prototype simply adds constexpr to the error message.
2. Removing and forcing everyone use the standard library version results in

   ```
   /usr/include/c++/6/cmath:1288:3: note: candidate: constexpr float std::copysign(float, float)
   copysign(float __x, float __y)
      ^~~~~~~~
   /projects/Vegastrike/engine/src/cmd/unit_generic.cpp:633:7: note: candidate: float copysign(float, float)
    float copysign( float x, float y )
          ^~~~~~~~
   /projects/Vegastrike/engine/src/cmd/unit_generic.cpp:3443:61: error: call of overloaded ‘copysign(float, const float&)’ is ambiguous
            Res.j = copysign( fuelclamp*limits.vertical, amt1.j );
                                                                ^
   In file included from /usr/include/features.h:364:0,
                    from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/6/bits/os_defines.h:39,
                    from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/6/bits/c++config.h:502,
                    from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_algobase.h:59,
                    from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_tree.h:63,
                    from /usr/include/c++/6/set:60,
                    from /projects/Vegastrike/engine/src/cmd/unit_generic.cpp:4:
   ```

Comment: If you can confirm that `copysign` in physics.h and `std::copysign` have the same behaviour, remove the `copysign` in physics.h and force everyone to use the std library version. A few other headers may need to pick up a cmath include, but you're ready to go into the future. Alternative is wrap the function in a `physics` namespace to prevent collisions like this.

Comment: Unfortunately it leads to an ambiguity error. Which I will add above shortly.

Comment: Oh and hard "IFNDEF cmath" was also used that would exclude it if the other one was present, same ambiguity.

Comment: My apologies. I neglected to advise you to also remove the implementation of `copysign` from the engine. Again, a `physics` namespace wrapping `copysign` and then replacing all `copysign`s in the engine with `physics::copysign` and updating the implementation to `physics::copysign` would eliminate the ambiguities and ensure that if physics's `copysign` and `std::copysign` differ in implementation that the engine would be using the physics `copysign`.

Comment: So far, while I've found the prototype I've yet to find the actual function. I am assuming at the moment that the prototype was a way of "specificity" rather than an actual prototype.

Comment: @user4581301 wanna write up that answer so I can give you credit? It got me to 17% compile :) I'm happy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer of course at least, so far as getting the compilation progress further ahead was to wrap the offending functions in a name space.

Thanks for the solution guys.

Answer (score 0):

just add ‘constexpr‘ in front of the forward declaration, so that it matches the declaration in cmath.

Comment: And what if the `copysign` in physics.h and `std::copysign` are implemented slightly or very differently?

Comment: error: ‘constexpr float copysign(float, float)’ conflicts with a previous declaration
 constexpr float copysign( float x, float y );

Answer (score 0):

I think if you squint at it the right way, then the code is not well-formed C++, even though it is well-formed C:

C allows user code to declare names from the C standard library and *not* include the relevant header.

C++ does *not* allow user code to (re)declare names from namespace `std`.

C++'s "C headers" (Annex D) say that it is unspecified whether names are first declared in namespace `std` in c*name* and then pulled into the global namespace in *name*.h via a *using-declaration* or the other way round. You therefore have to assume that when you use the compatibility header *name*.h in C++ and use a global name, that name may have been declared in namespace `std` and that the global namespace contains a *using-declaration*, and you are therefore not allowed to declare that name.

In a nutshell, not all C code is valid C++, and you've struck an example of this. The particular cause of your problem is that your C++ library has chosen to add `constexpr` to its declaration of `copysign`, which it is allowed to do, because it assumes that you aren't declaring its names.

Comment: In other words you are recommending to wrap it in its own name space as @user4581301 [advocates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42497960/c-overloaded-copysign-operator-either-conflicting-or-ambiguous#comment72135706_42497960) ?

Comment: @Myut: I wasn't recommending anything, although that would seem to be a plausible solution.

Comment: It does appear to be a valid solution as it got me a bit further through the compile process. Now...I did try to upvote but due to lack of reputation... it's been "recorded" but not "displayed". Goddamn elitists.